# Is it possible to show the real domain name when reaching the s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cname

I would like to show my domain name (*www.example.com*) and not the bucket's endpoint (example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com) when pointing the browser to it.
Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need SSL?  There's one solution if you do, and a different solution if you don't.

Comment: I'm not sure if in the future I'll need it. By now, What is the most correct between the two? :D

Comment: You've suggested in another comment that you type one name into the browser, then it switches to the bucket.  Is that right?  You type `www.example.com` but you see `example.com.s3-website...` and no `www`?  Or the opposite?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly like that. I type www.example.com and I get example.com.s3....

Comment: This sounds like a reasonably common misconfiguration.  You have a bad setting on the www.example.com bucket.  "Redirect all requests" should point to "example.com" -- not the web site endpoint hostname of the example.com bucket -- and that would cause exactly this behavior.

Comment: I tried to change the pointing address but the website became unreachable. It is strange because Route53 is pointing the correct bucket. There are 2 cname records: one for the example.com that point to the bucket with the same name; the other with "www" that point to the bucket with the name "www.example.com". So, I don't know the reason why the website become unreachable when I try to change the bucket redirect settings.

Comment: It's important to be precise in your descriptions.  What does "became unreachable" mean?  Also, a CNAME record for example.com is invalid and should be impossible to configure. You need an A record with "Alias" set to "Yes" and the bucket website endpoint selected in the target list... not a CNAME.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry ..a slip :)

Comment: I just changed the settings again. This time nothing happened. I continue to see the same addresses in the browser. 
P.S.: I wrote unreachable because I got an error about the DNS  in the browser. Right now I can't remember the error message.

Comment: Is the example.com bucket accessible at `example.com`?  If not, focus on fixing that part first? before worrying about the redirect from www.example.com to example.com, so that you minimize the number of unknowns.

Comment: Yes, it is accessible at example.com.

Comment: Okay, that's good.  So what is the www site doing, now?

Comment: It is pointing its bucket. I can see the "index.html" page with both links (www and not).

Comment: Update: Now the error message again:
This site can’t be reached

example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED